# How shift a part of the long table to the next page in LATEX?

Tags: tables

I have a long table in LATEX, where is not visible completely in a page.

I want to shift a percentage of a table into the next page. e.g., 70% of the table in the current page and remained 30% in the next page.

How is it possible in LATEX?

Comment: What does your table contain? Big paragraph texts? If *not*, you could use [`longtable`](http://ctan.org/pkg/longtable) that allows breaking across pages between *rows* (not mid-row though).

Comment: Thank you friend! How can i shift caption of the table from bottom of the table to over? when I use \caption{} immediately after \begin{longtable}, it gives error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can move material to the next page with `\pagebreak`.

Part on page 1:

[image: Page 1]

Part on page 2:

[image: Page 2]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{lr}
  \caption{A sample long table}\\
  \hline
  Left&Right\\
  \hline
  \endhead
  X&Y\\
  A&B\\
  \pagebreak
  C&D
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Note that you need `\\` after the `\caption{...}` command.